# Is weathering a form of friction?

Tags: friction

Suppose I have a surface out in the wild somewhere. Let's suppose further that over time, this surface is eroded due to any typical form of erosion / weathering. Is this weathering due to a cumulative form of friction?

I know for instance my shoes wear down when I walk and I assume this degradation is due to friction. Thus, it made me wonder whether weathering in natural settings is due to friction.

No abuse of terms intended.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, erosion by wind, air, dust, sand, is a form of friction. But wahtering can also happen for other causes, such as chemical reactions like corrosion, oxidation, etc.